# Google searching in Java

Tags: java, search

This program reads takes a text file of search queries, queries Google with them, and outputs all of the links to another file. The program works for a few hundred queries, but suddenly working and reports an error.

(I will edit this post and post what errors are being returned from which lines of my program soon).

Any ideas what might be happening?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GoogleSearcher {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Input list of queries to search:");
    String loc = in.nextLine();
    loc = loc.replace("\\", "");
    System.out.println("Where to write file?");
    String writeLoc = in.nextLine();
    writeLoc = writeLoc.replace("\\", " ");
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(loc);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String line;
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(writeLoc + "Google Search Results.txt"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println("Searching: \"" + line + "\"");
      ArrayList<String> t = googleSearch(line);
      if (t != null){
        for (int a = 0; a < t.size(); a++){
          pw.write(t.get(a) + System.lineSeparator());
        }
      }
    }
    br.close();
    pw.close();
  }
  public static ArrayList<String> googleSearch(String search) throws Exception {
    try {
      String query = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search.replace(" ", "%20");
      String page = getSearchContent(query);
      ArrayList<String> links = parseLinks(page);
      return formatLinks(links);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Error... Trying next search");
      return null;
    } 
  }
  public static ArrayList<String> formatLinks(ArrayList a){
    ArrayList<String> formatted = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
      String t = (String)a.get(i);
      t = t.replace("%3F", "?");
      t = t.replace("%3D", "=");
      formatted.add(t);
    }
    return formatted;
  }
  public static String getString(InputStream is) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    try {
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (br != null) {
        try {
          br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
  public static String getSearchContent(String path) throws Exception {
    final String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)";
    URL url = new URL(path);
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", agent);
    final InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
    return getString(stream);
  }
  public static ArrayList<String> parseLinks(final String html) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String pattern1 = "<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\"/url?q=";
    String pattern2 = "\">";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    while (m.find()) {
      String domainName = m.group(0).trim();
      // remove unwanted text
      domainName = domainName.substring(domainName.indexOf("/url?q=") + 7);
      domainName = domainName.substring(0, domainName.indexOf("&amp;"));
      result.add(domainName);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Google likely blocks this type of automated use of their services.

Comment: Yeah, what's the error? I tried with around 300 words and it seems to run fine..

Comment: You should trap/log all status codes and errors, particularly those returned from the Google service. As @ti7 said, there are many sites that track the number and rate of connections/queries and block clients that exceed the threshold.  Usually when it sees a certain number of requests are made in a certain period of time, so if you can figure out what that is you might be able to throttle back your code. You could leave it running connecting as some rate, track when google stops responding and when it starts working again, and fiddle with the rate, and try to find a pattern. Also google it :)

Comment: The error is that Google blocks automated searches after a while and I'm trying to find a way around it because I have a few thousand queries to log.. I might actually try the throttling my code back a bit, I'll google how to do that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after running several rounds of your program, I got the following error.

```
Error... Trying next search
Searching: "autoradiograph"
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Daustria&q=EgTLe7ahGOKSrcMFIhkA8aeDSylzciRE9l0cz9fUg6u2MeGh-muxMgNyY24
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at application.GoogleSearcher.getSearchContent(GoogleSearcher.java:90)
    at application.GoogleSearcher.googleSearch(GoogleSearcher.java:45)
    at application.GoogleSearcher.main(GoogleSearcher.java:32)
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dautoradiograph&q=EgTLe7ahGOKSrcMFIhkA8aeDS_cQehdQreptc4cInLKEPYpprweeMgNyY24
```

This is happening, because google is blocking automated searches to prevent a [Denial of Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack on their server.

[image: Google Captcha Image]

Google might not allow you to perform automated searches. Here's a [link to their support page.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en). Here's an extract from that page.

> **Automated queries**
>
> Google's Terms of Service do not allow the sending of automated queries of any sort to our system without express permission in advance from Google. Sending automated queries consumes resources and includes using any software (such as WebPosition Gold) to send automated queries to Google to determine how a website or webpage ranks in Google search results for various queries. In addition to rank checking, other types of automated access to Google without permission are also a violation of our Webmaster Guidelines and Terms of Service.

Comment: You can use this [Java library](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-java), it takes care of CAPTCHA and proxies.

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's designed in that way. Whenever Google detects that some sort of automated software is fetching it's results, it will ask for human verification and shows a CAPTCHA.

[See this answer from support.google.com.](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en)

> **"Unusual traffic from your computer network"**
>
> You might see "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your
>   computer network" if it seems like a computer or phone on your network
>   is sending automated traffic to Google.
>
> **What Google considers automated traffic**
>
> - Sending searches from a robot, computer program, automated service, or search scraper
> - Using software that sends searches to Google to see how a website or webpage ranks on Google
>
> **What to do when you see this message**
>
> The error page most likely shows a CAPTCHA (a squiggly word with a box
>   below it). To continue using Google, type the squiggly word into the
>   box. It's how we know you're a human, not a robot. After you type the
>   CAPTCHA correctly, the message will go away and you can use Google
>   again.

---

If you want to use google search in your website, then you can use [Google Custom Search](https://cse.google.com) that's created for this purpose only.

See also: [Add search to your site](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en)